# Trouble installing Supervisor on Amazon Linux with easy_install

Tags: elastic-beanstalk, supervisord, easy-install

Our automated build process suddenly stopped functioning today with a fault installing "supervisor". I get the same fault after a complete rebuild. Does anybody have an alternative EB compatible method for installing Supervisor? Or any other tips on what to do?

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-25-243 /]$ sudo easy_install supervisor
Searching for supervisor
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/supervisor/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/7f/c780b7471ba0ff4548967a9f7a8b0bfce222c3a496c3dfad0164172222b0/supervisor-4.2.2.tar.gz#sha256=5b2b8882ec8a3c3733cce6965cc098b6d80b417f21229ab90b18fe551d619f90
error: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/7f/c780b7471ba0ff4548967a9f7a8b0bfce222c3a496c3dfad0164172222b0/supervisor-4.2.2.tar.gz#sha256=5b2b8882ec8a3c3733cce6965cc098b6d80b417f21229ab90b18fe551d619f90 hostname 'files.pythonhosted.org' doesn't match either of 'r.ssl.fastly.net', '*.catchpoint.com', '*.cnn.io', '******'
```

I can't include the actual list of domains as StackExchange raises a "spam" warning.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by changing `easy_install supervisor` to `pip install supervisor`

(see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=978418)